# if an unnamed semaphore is initialized in shared memory, does shm_unlink() destroy the semaphore?

Tags: c, posix, semaphore, shared-memory

I'm using POSIX semaphores and shared memory to coordinate a single producer and single consumer buffer. I want to completely initialize this shared memory and semaphore, whether or not the shared memory is named or is being used. This is the function I want to use:

```c
/* shared data */
typedef struct {
    sem_t sem;
    size_t head;
    size_t tail;
} shared_struct;

shared_struct * create_shmem_struct(const char *name) {

    /* re-open shared memory */
    shm_unlink(name);
    int fd = shm_open (name, (O_CREAT | O_RDWR), (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR));
    ftruncate (fd, sizeof(shared_struct));
    shared_struct *ptr = (shared_struct *) mmap (NULL, sizeof(shared_struct), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    close (fd);

    /* initialize semaphore */
    /* can i do this here? : sem_destroy(&ptr->sem); */
    sem_init(&ptr->sem, 1, 1);

    return ptr;
}
```

What happens to the semaphore if it already is initialized but no `sem_destroy` is called before `shm_unlink`? Does it hurt to call `sem_destroy` on a possibly uninitialized unnamed semaphore before `sem_init`?

I should note, I'm basing this strategy on Michael Kerrisk's slides from the man pages [found here](http://man7.org/training/download/posix_shm_slides.pdf).

Comment: `man sem_destroy`: *Only a semaphore  that  has  been  initialized  by  sem_init(3)  should  be destroyed using sem_destroy().*

Comment: OK so if I can't `sem_destroy()` then what if `shm_unlink` does NOT destroy the shared memory (since it may still be open in another process). In this case, would the semaphore in shared memory persist and still be initialized. In this case, a call to `sem_init()` is also illegal. How to reset the seamphore?

Comment: `man sem_unlink`: *The operation of shm_unlink() is  analogous  to  unlink(2):  it  removes  a shared  memory  object  name[...] After a successful shm_unlink(), attempts to shm_open() an object with the same name will fail (unless O_CREAT was specified, in which case a new, distinct object is created).* You can create a new semaphore with the same name, since the old one is no longer reachable through this name.